# Как сделать загрузчик своей ОС для UEFI/GPT?

Tags: bios, uefi, системное-программирование

Понятно, как сделать загрузчик для BIOS/MBR - в первые 446 байт первого сектора накопителя вставляем свой код, а последние два байта первого сектора устанавливаем как aa и 55. Все просто.
А как сделать то же самое, но только для UEFI/GPT? Совсем непонятен именно процесс загрузки ОС на UEFI, из какого сектора берется загрузчик, в Real Mode ли работает процессор с UEFI при включении и так далее.
Погуглил на русском и английском, но ничего нормального нашел (хотя, возможно, плохо или не то искал). Странно то, что про BIOS/MBR в интернете все описано самым подробнейшим образом, а про UEFI/GPT наоборот

Comment: [UEFI deployment guide](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_on_Dell%20BizClient_Platforms.pdf)

Comment: @Grundy так ведь это не то, там просто объясняются преимущества и особенности, но ничего конкретного. или я тупой и не заметил просто?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI

Comment: https://uefi.org/specifications